# Strange assignment behavior with dictionary in nested loops

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, variable-assignment

So I need to rearrange some values in my dictionary. Specifically, for 'Verb', the list comes before 'verb three', and I'd like it to come right after. I'm trying to use the `foo[i], foo[j] = foo[j], foo[i]` swapping method on a dummy list which I'll then assign over the original. Like so:

```
test_dict = {'Noun': ['noun one', 'noun two', 'noun three'], 
             'Verb': ['verb one', 'verb two', ['list one', 'list two',
                      'list three'], 'verb three', 'verb four']}

e = test_dict

for key in sorted(e):
    fixed_list = e[key]
    print('    ', key)
    for i in range(0, len(e[key])):
        print(i)
        print(type(e[key][i]))    
        if type(e[key][i]) == list:  
            print('ooh, this one\'s a list!', e[key][i])
            print('   and here it is in fixed_list: ', fixed_list[i])
            fixed_list[i], fixed_list[i+1] = fixed_list[i+1], fixed_list[i]
    e[key] = fixed_list
```

However, the bizarre output I get is [Note: the list in my 'Verb' key will **never** come last, so ignore the IndexError]:

```
 Noun
0
<class 'str'>
1
<class 'str'>
2
<class 'str'>

 Verb
0
<class 'str'>
1
<class 'str'>
2
<class 'list'>
ooh, this one's a list! ['list one', 'list two', 'list three']
and here it is in fixed_list:  ['list one', 'list two', 'list three']
3
<class 'list'>
ooh, this one's a list! ['list one', 'list two', 'list three']
and here it is in fixed_list:  ['list one', 'list two', 'list three']
4
<class 'list'>
ooh, this one's a list! ['list one', 'list two', 'list three']
and here it is in fixed_list:  ['list one', 'list two', 'list three']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_project.py", line 567, in <module>
fixed_list[i], fixed_list[i+1] = fixed_list[i+1], fixed_list[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now, unless I'm crazy, it seems like reassigning elements of fixed_list is causing issues in the key's value list inside the inner loop, but how? The only time they 'touch' each other assignment-wise is at the beginning and end of the outer loop.

Comment: `fixed_list = e[key]` does not create a copy. All you did is create another reference to the same list object. You are then altering the list you are already iterating over.

Comment: @depperm: so? They sorted the keys, and are only handling the lists, which *are* ordered.

Comment: @depperm: yes, and both are objects in a list. Which has ordering.

Comment: Mostly unrelated but you can use `isinstance(obj, list)`.  Direct comparison with `type(obj)` is *sometimes* correct if you know what you're doing, but is generally an anti-pattern.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that would explain the behavior, thank you very much for solving my head-scratcher.

Comment: @Iguananaut thanks for the tip; not certain what 'anti-pattern' entails, but I'll take your word for it and make it more correct.

Comment: You can use pythontutor.com to visualise how this works.